# Why XML Character constraint is asymmetric?

Tags: xml, special-characters

Is not clear to me the logic behind the asymmerty in XML characters validation.

For example the subsequent XMLs are not valid (as i expect) :

```
<xml>
<value attr="<">my value</value>
</xml>

<xml>
<value attr="attribute">my value is < than</value>
</xml>
```

But those XMLs are valid

```
<xml>
<value attr=">">my value</value>
</xml>

<xml>
<value attr="attribute">my value is > than</value>
</xml>
```

What i'm expecting is that any characters like 
`<>&` should be always considered as illegal.
So i would like to ask which are the reason of that choice (> is fine but < is not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grammar rules were written to obviate the need for parsers to have to scan ahead to properly interpret characters.

The difference between `<` and `>` is that the parser upon encountering `<` cannot know whether it's the start of a tag or a LESS THAN character without scanning forward, whereas when encountering `>`, the parser knows based upon its scan history (without having to scan ahead) whether it should be interpreted as end of tag or a GREATER THAN character.

**See also:**

- [**Simplified XML Escaping**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)
- Michael Kay's [**helpful comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584190/why-xml-character-constraint-is-asymmetric/50586560?noredirect=1#comment88184874_50586560) regarding SGML compatibility and rule uniformity.

Comment: The actual reasons are more complex than that. XML could easily have allowed both `<` and `>` to appear unescaped in attribute values without causing parsers any difficulty. The reason it allows `>` but not `<` is to partly do with SGML compatibility, which was considered important in the early days of XML, and partly so the rules for attributes are the same as the rules for text nodes.

Comment: @MichaelKay @kjhughes SGML accepts `<` in quoted attribute value specifications, so suggesting this is a legacy restriction XML has inherited from SGML is completely incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I'm also very perplexed about this.

Upon first scanning through the spec my mind immediately thought ">" was the invalid character, since it's much harder to "jump" to the end of the element if thats a valid character *inside* of the element. It was first later on, when I browsed through the spec more thoroughly I realized it really was "<" that wasn't allowed. What!?

This actually makes no sense to me. I've read the explanation given here, and others, and, well... no... Just no. Can't wrap my head around it... Scan ahead? What? If the parser scans each character - moving forward - it can easily build a context of where it is, so both should be allowed. BUT! And this is the kicker for me: If you'd like to "skip ahead", fast, to just get to the end of the element, using a method you have in your programming language, you're probably left with some kind of instr/indexOf-method. But you can't use them, since you have to keep building and updating your context when doing this! You need to parse each and every attribute - according to spec - even though you know you're not interested in this particular element! Wow... This really blows my mind.

These *both* characters should of course be disallowed inside of an element, if you ask me, but since one of them is allowed - so should the other. But I rather see them both go. Well, too late now.

Sorry for whining on an old subject.

PS. Yes. I just wrote my own XML-parser. So I'm a bit frustrated right now. And no, don't ever write your own XML-parser if you don't have to. ;)

Comment: Also, allowing whitespace inside the end-tag is a blunder. I mean, why? It adds nothing, but extra work for parsers. In the start-tag, of course, fine, but in the end-tag? No.

We should release a XML "2.0" with all this nonsense fixed.